# Mac OSX-Lion Python-LDAP Unrecognized Symbol: _ber_pvt_opt_on

Tags: python, osx-lion, python-ldap

I've been trying to run a web server based in Python 2.6 code here at work.  The server requires the python LDAP libraries in order to run.  Because I'm working on Mac OS X Lion, I needed to run a manual install of python-ldap 2.4.7 in order to get Python to recognize LDAP at all.  Python-ldap appeared to intall correctly, but when I try to run the web server I get the following error (I added some line breaks for the sake of clarity):

**ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_ldap-2.4.7-py2.6-macosx-10.7-fat.egg/_ldap.so, 2): Symbol not found: _ber_pvt_opt_on**

**Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_ldap-2.4.7-py2.6-macosx-10.7-fat.egg/_ldap.so**

**Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_ldap-2.4.7-py2.6-macosx-10.7-fat.egg/_ldap.so**

I'm using OpenLDAP 2.4.21, and I set the following system variables before running my python-ldap installation:

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386"
export CFLAGS="-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -arch i386"
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="10.7"
```

I should also probably mention that I've had to force everything I've installed to use 32-bit architecture instead of 64-bit in order to work around some issues with Oracle's 64-bit support.  Has anyone encountered a similar situation, or do they know the significance of the "_ber_pvt_opt_on" symbol that LDAP was looking for?  The number of Google results I was able to come up with was both small and unhelpful.  Any light that you could shed on the situation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you try installing python and the LDAP library through **Macport**? It is usually the recommended way.

Comment: MacPorts produces its own brand of errors, as I've since discovered.  Most notable among them is "Incompatible library version: LDAP requires version 3.0.0 or later, but libsasl2.2.dylib provides version 0.0.0", which led me to an open ticket on the MacPorts site: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/32391  Needless to say, that wasn't terribly encouraging.

Comment: I've found that using python-ldap==2.3.13 works with the native openldap that comes with Lion.  I've tried many attempts to get the latest python-ldap working with no success.